# Get filename from database and use it to populate an ImageView

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm creating an app which at this point needs to get a filename from a sqlite database, get the image with that filename and insert it in an ImageView, i've created this code right now, but i think i'm doing everything wrong here...

```
Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = db.getReadableDatabase();
final Cursor curFileName = readableDatabase.rawQuery("select filename from data order by id asc", null);
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
int filename = curFileName.getColumnIndex("filename");
String filenameString = curFileName.getString(filename);
d = Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+filenameString);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filenameString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
handleDrawable(d);
```

yes sorry, this is the exception:

```
04-09 13:48:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30802): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 13:48:16.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30802): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{g.d.filer/g.d.filer.Favorites}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 33
```

Comment: Did you get any exception ? Did you give permission to read file from External storage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must position the cursor before you can read

```
 int filename = curFileName.getColumnIndex("filename");
 if (cur.moveToFirst()) { // position cursor to first item. false: empty resultset
     String filenameString = curFileName.getString(filename);
     d = Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+filenameString);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filenameString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     handleDrawable(d);
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had edited my answer. I hope this will help u. :D

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
   do{
      String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("filename"));
      // here you have to generate Image view and add bitmap to imageview
   }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close()
```

Comment: i dont't think there's anything wrong with how i create the image, actually it gives me an error relative to the cursor

Comment: yes check with your ColumnIndex("filename"). Is filename is available in your table

Comment: i'm new to this, but if i'm not wrong, where i've put "filename" there should be the column name right? when i create the database (which creates and populates with no problem) i've created a column with that name

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

or

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in the manifest file.
Because, beginning with Android 4.4, these permissions are not required if you're reading or writing only files that are private to your app. For more information, see

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal